# Controlling particle textures

Tags: texturing, particles

How do we control particles to have a certain amount of textures; consider a blade of grass:
[image]
Suppose we wanted to add bumps with parallel lines to give them a vein kind of effect like so:
[image]
How do we achieve this? If we apply an image texture, the particle being emitted from that portion takes only that color from the part being emitted but it doesn't apply for the particle itself.
Furthermore, if detail of smaller fuzzy particles were to be given to provide it a more natural rim, how do we do it with particles?
We could model some objects and add them to particle system but if we wanted to add the simulation of grass with the wind, that would not be very realistic. So, how do we add textures to individual particles?

Answer (score 1):

If it's cycles you are using it might be possible. All of the particles do have a unique ID that you maybe can use to give them different textures. The ID is used to calculate ag. collisions, if i haven't misunderstand how it works. 
In the math node should it be an options for compare values, if you set it to check if the value is the same and if they are it will send 1. 
You should be able to do it but I'm not sure if it is worth the extra time.

Comment: I don't really understand how it works. And I don't really know if there are other ways to texture particles, is there? Not just their color, I mean, the bumps in them, the extra particles that grow out of the particles and the ability to fully interact with force fields.

Comment: It's probebly easier to use the particle system as a referens and make animated objects that uses different materials than it is to make one complex material that have all the information that is needed for every particle

Comment: Every particle do most likely have a ID to keep track on ther age, speed and the other thing that are commonly used. That ID can probebly be used to make an YberMaterial for the particles.

Comment: "Yber Material???", a new type. The lastest I heard was a PBR shader material